# Is there a way to define "area" of a non-discrete & non-empty open or closed bounded subset of complex plane, topologically?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

One of the properties of a non-discrete & non-empty , open or closed bounded subset of a complex plane could be "Area". Is there a way to define "area" of such a set in topological terms ?

Answer (score 4):

No, not in any useful way, as $f(z)= \alpha z$ for $\alpha >0$ in the reals is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb C$ and if we could define $\operatorname{area}(U)$ in purely topological terms, $U$ and $\alpha U = f[U]$ would have the same value, even though we stretched or shrunk $U$ by $\alpha$. E.g. You would intuitively expect that the unit disk has a smaller area than the disk of radius 2, but they're homeomorphic, so a topological definition would have to give them the same value, so no monotonicity (larger subsets have larger area) can hold.